# How do you keep a ruby project running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I currently have a Redmine installation on a local server for our office to use. The problem is that sometimes, when I run the redmine server using:

> ruby script/server webrick -e production

it will sometime kill the process due to some error. The error is not the issue, but what I want is a way to re-run the process, and have it automatically run whenever it is seen not running.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run it under process supervisor, which will try (and possibly succeed) to start process again after it has died. I suggest [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/), but you can also try daemontools ar monit.